# Extract post code from an address string - JavaScript - UK

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to be able to get a postcode from a random string.

Strings I may receive

```
2 Castlebar Park, London, Greater London W5 1BX, UK
The Ludgrove Club, Alan Drive, Barnet EN5 2PU
The Ludgrove Club, Alan Drive, Barnet EN52PU
The Ludgrove Club, Alan Drive, Barnet E5, UK
```

These are just examples to demonstrate what they might look like.

What I have so far is:

```
'The Ludgrove Club, Alan Drive, Barnet EN5 2PU'.match(/^([A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9A-Za-z]{1,2})[ ]?([0-9]{0,1}[A-Za-z]{2})$/)
//returns null
```

This works on post codes, but not if they are part of a larger string.

Comment: In case of "...Barnet E5, UK", is postcode you want is E5 or "E5, UK"?

Comment: Just E5. Never UK :)

Comment: Your regex matches the whole string because it starts with `^` and ends with `$`. If you remove those, they'll match partial strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Improving @Paul Armstrong answer a bit, in case of a whole string:

```
"The Ludgrove Club, Alan Drive, Barnet EN5 2PU".split(",").map(s => s.trim().match(/([A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{1,2})(\s?(\d?\w{2}))?/)).filter(e => e)[0][0]
```

returns "EN5 2PU"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking to match "EN52PU" as well as "EN5 2PU" as well as just "E5". This should do the trick:

```
/[A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{1,2}(?:\s?(?:\d?\w{2}))?/
```

See in action with explanations here: https://regex101.com/r/Nbvu58/2

Answer (score 1):

I would check that the zip code starts from a word break, and that the end of it is delimited by a comma or end-of-string:

```
/(\b[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}( ?\d?[A-Z]{2})?)(?=,|$)/
```

```js
// Sample data
[
    '2 Castlebar Park, London, Greater London W5 1BX, UK',
    'The Ludgrove Club, Alan Drive, Barnet EN5 2PU',
    'The Ludgrove Club, Alan Drive, Barnet EN52PU',
    'The Ludgrove Club, Alan Drive, Barnet E5, UK'
].forEach(input => { // Iterate over them
    var m = input.match(/(\b[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}( ?\d?[A-Z]{2})?)(?=,|$)/);
    if (m) console.log(m[0]); // Output match
});
```